# Cannot retain value in Java recursive call?

Tags: java, recursion, static, hashset, recursive-datastructures

I have the following method in my Java app:

```
public List<UUID> recursiveMethod(UUID productUuid) {
    Set<UUID> productUuidSet = new HashSet<>();
    productUuidSet.add(productUuid);

    List<Product> subProducts = productRepo.getSubProducts(productUuid);

    for (Product subProduct : subProducts) {
        final UUID subProductUuid = subProduct.getProductUuid();

        productUuidSet.add(subProductUuid);
        productUuidSet.addAll(recursiveMethod(subProductUuid));
    }

    return new ArrayList<>(productUuidSet);
}
```

As far as I know, recursive method keep each call result recursively. And, when calling the recursive method via `productUuidSet.addAll(recursiveMethod(subProductUuid));`, it creates a new `HashSet`, but as it returns the value inside the `HashSet`, I would be able to keep it in `productUuidSet` after recursive call.

So, what is wrong with this method? If there is a problem, how can I retain `productUuidSet` value by adding result after each recursive call?

Comment: 1) This second line `productUuidSet.add(subProductUuid);` is not needed, it will be added in the `productUuidSet.addAll(recursiveMethod(subProductUuid));` call. 2) Produce some output what items have been added. From looking at the code, it looks correct, but my concerns are with `productRepo.getSubProducts(productUuid);` if it actually delivers the right IDs. Remeber: there might be all duplicates, but `Set` will swallow duplicates, maybe 'truncation' your output.

Comment: @JayC667 Thanks a lot amigo, your comment is really useful and I solved the problem with the help of you. Regards.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, you want to keep the set rather than creating new set each time?

This should work:

```
public List<UUID> recursiveMethod(UUID productUuid) {
  Set<UUID> productUuidSet = new HashSet<>(); // or LinkedHashSet if order matters
  recursiveMethod0(productUuidSet, productUuid);
  return new ArrayList<>(productUuidSet);
}

private void recursiveMethod0(Set<UUID> productUuidSet, UUID productUuid) {
    productUuidSet.add(productUuid);
    List<Product> subProducts = productRepo.getSubProducts(productUuid);
    for (Product subProduct : subProducts) {
        recursiveMethod0(productUuidSet, subProduct.getProductUuid());
    }
}
```

TL;DR: simply pass the set instead of recreating it each time.

I simplified your insertion code: `productUuidSet.add(subProductUuid);` is already done by the recursive function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, but I need to use the same method only. I fixed the problem with the help of @JayZ, but I want to vote up your answer if I get enough repo.

Comment: Any vote up pls for my question so that I can vote up your answer?